# Регулярное выражение для замены диапазона в IMPORTRANGE

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-spreadsheet

В колонку импортируются значения из другого документа.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1yNnsZm_k7cLE94RTnNIsWM5PCqYF4SWc851t_k0WyJ8", "Исходные 2019!O5:Q5")
```

И так в каждой ячейке колонки (20 строк), меняется только номер строки импортируемого диапазона (O5:Q5)

Я выделяю этот диапазон (20 строк) и хочу в нем заменить D5:E5 на R5:W5, например.

Использую для этого "Найти и заменить"
Но не могу понять, как написать регулярное выражение для замены.

O[0-9]:Q[0-9] на R[0-9]:W[0-9] не работает с галочкой "Искать с регулярными выражениями" не работает

В каждой ячейке столбца все то же самое, кроме номера строки - он меняется.
Нужно заменить сами столбцы, не меняя строки.
То есть O6:Q6  → R6:W6.
O7:Q7 → R7:W7.
И так далее.

Если просто руками это делать, то это в каждую ячейку нужно залазить.
А я хотела выделить весь диапазон, чтобы во всем диапазоне заменить
O*:Q* → R*:W*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если O на R и Q на W ? так даже в моем стареньком умеет менять :)

Comment: А просто растянуть новую формулу - не вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `O(\d+):Q(\d+)` на `R$1:W$2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]